# Acentuação gráfica

Tags: suporte

Eu sei que devemos prezar pelo uso do português o mais correto e seguir as normas tão bem quanto nossa habilidade permite.

No entanto, uso o site direto por um computador que possui o teclado em inglês canadense e francês. Como não tenho direitos para mudar o layout neste computador para português, o que geralmente faço é tentar seguir e colocar acentuação mínima enquanto estou aqui. Pois acredito que as mensagens são claras o bastante para entender. E depois edito quando chego em casa, para deixar da forma que deveria ter postado.

**Qual deveria ser minha atitude com relação a isso?**

Comment: Instale um dicionário de Português no seu *browser* e ele lhe indicará todas a correções, não precisando se preocupar com os acentos, é um bocado chato mas eu próprio uso, porque alguma vez me esqueço de alguns.

Comment: Até onde sei, um teclado em francês deve ter os acentos agudo (´) e circunflexo (^). Tenho 100% e certeza quanto ao agudo. Deve ser possível fazer também uma cedilha (ç) "acentuando-se" a letra c com agudo, acredito.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creio que não é preciso se preocupar demais com isso não. Estando compreensível, é isso que importa. É mais ou menos como aquela questão da pessoa não falar bem o idioma, mas ainda assim utilizá-lo: ninguém vai jogar pedra só por não estar no português 100% correto. É um tipo de limitação comum. Da mesma forma, limitações relativas ao método de entrada de caracteres acentuados pode não ser mais comum nos dias de hoje, mas eu pelo menos sou velho o bastante pra me lembrar da época que era hehe.

De qualquer forma, se você tiver interesse - e não tiver nenhuma objeção a bookmarklets (eu acho que a utilidade deles só é superada pelas suas implicações negativas na segurança rsrs) - eu montei um pequeno código que pode te ajudar (nem que seja pra não ter que fazer a conversão na mão):

Forma extendida:

```
(function () {
    var t = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        t[i].value = t[i].value.replace(/['^~][aeioucn]/gi, function (x) {
            return {
                "'a": 'á', "'e": 'é', "'i": 'í', "'o": 'ó', "'u": 'ú', "'c": 'ç',
                "^a": 'â', "^e": 'ê', "^i": 'î', "^o": 'ô', "^u": 'û',
                "~a": 'ã', "~o": 'õ', '~n': 'ñ',
                "'A": 'Á', "'E": 'É', "'I": 'Í', "'O": 'Ó', "'U": 'Ú', "'C": 'Ç',
                "^A": 'Â', "^E": 'Ê', "^I": 'Î', "^O": 'Ô', "^U": 'Û',
                "~A": 'Ã', "~O": 'Õ', '~N': 'Ñ'
            }[x] || x;
        });
    }
})();
```

Forma curta (eu criaria um link pra você simplesmente arrastar e soltar na barra de favoritos, mas o Stack Exchange - sabiamente - não permite isso):

```
javascript:(function(){var t=document.querySelectorAll("textarea");for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++){t[i].value=t[i].value.replace(/['^~][aeioucn]/gi,function(x){return {"'a":'á',"'e":'é',"'i":'í',"'o":'ó',"'u":'ú',"'c":'ç',"^a":'â',"^e":'ê',"^i":'î',"^o":'ô',"^u":'û',"~a":'ã',"~o":'õ','~n':'ñ',"'A":'Á',"'E":'É',"'I":'Í',"'O":'Ó',"'U":'Ú',"'C":'Ç',"^A":'Â',"^E":'Ê',"^I":'Î',"^O":'Ô',"^U":'Û',"~A":'Ã',"~O":'Õ','~N':'Ñ'}[x]||x;});}})();
```

Usei esse próprio post pra testar, se achar um erro de acentuação então você achou um bug hehe. Para usar, simplesmente escreva em qualquer `textarea` como faria normalmente (ex.: 'c ~a 'e) e ao clicar no bookmarklet ele vai converter em acentos (ç ã é). Verifique se não afetou nenhum trecho de código na sua pergunta/resposta (strings que usem single quotes e comecem com uma vogal ou c), e pronto!

Comment: +1 Grande resposta!